# Canvas for drawing is a circle; random dots within canvas

Tags: java, math

I'm practicing for an exam, and I'm doing one of the practice problems. I have a method that takes two arguments: one for the radius of a circle, and one for the number of dots to place within that circle. The method is below:

```
private void drawDots(int radius, int numDots){
    double ycord;
    double xcord;
    for(int q = 0; q < numDots; q++){
        ycord = -radius + random()*(radius+radius+1);
        xcord = pow((pow(radius,2)-pow(ycord,2)),0.5);
        turt.moveTo(xcord,ycord);
        turt.penDown();
        turt.forward(0);
        turt.penUp();
    }
}
```

`turt` is an object I'm using to draw with, and `penDown()`/`penUp()` is placing and removing the object from the canvas respectively.

I'm trying to define the x-coordinate and y-coordinate of the `turt` object to stay within a radius. Say the radius is `100`, and the number of dots is `200`, how do I keep the object within that radius?

The question states that:

"To constain the dots to a circle of radius r, a random y-coord in the interval -r, r is chosen. To x-coord is then randomly chosen in the interval -b, b, where b = sqrt(r^2 - y^2)."

I'm just not sure how to make sense of this math. The code above was my best attempt, but the output is strange.

Here is my failed output:

[image]

Comment: this is pythagorean theorem. try to visualize the right-angled triangle. the line from the center of the circle to the x-coordinate of your dot is the hypotenuse. that's how the equation comes about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distance from the center `(0,0)` to a dot must be less than the radius of the circle, `r`. The distance can be expressed as `sqrt(x² + y²)`. Therefore, if you choose your `y` coordinate randomly between `[-r, r]`, you just have to make sure that your `x` coordinate respects the previous equation, hence your math.

Demonstration

```
sqrt(x² + y²) < r
x² + y² < r²
x² < r² - y²
x < sqrt(r² - y²)
#
```

Your algorithm should be as follows. Once you chose the y coordinate, you can randomly choose x as long as it respects the distance constraint.

```
private void drawDots(int radius, int numDots){
    double y;
    double x;
    double xMax;

    for (int q = 0; q < numDots; q++){
        // y is chosen randomly
        y = -radius + random() * (radius + radius + 1);

        // x must respect x² + y² < r²
        xMax = pow((pow(radius,2)-pow(ycord,2)), 0.5);
        x = random() * 2 * xMax - xMax;

        turt.moveTo(x, y);
        turt.penDown();
        turt.forward(0);
        turt.penUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly. you considered the constraint to be dist = r, instead of dist < r. Try your algorithm with 10000+ points, it should cover the area pretty well (assuming your random generator is uniform).

Comment: Just curious: why do some points still fall outside the radius? If you'll see the OP question, there's a few dots clearly outside in the top-left corner. Even with corrected code, I still get a few there. Is this just uncaught errors or there is a problem with the code?

Comment: Indeed. You have one point at the origin of your canvas, and one dot with y = r and x at the origin of the canvas. Try to launch your initial algorithm with two points, it may be an initialization error of the moveTo() function.

Answer (score 1):

At present you are drawing points on the circle, not inside it. That is because you are not following the guideline correctly.

```
b = pow((pow(radius,2)-pow(ycord,2)),0.5); // this should be b
xcord = -b + random()*(b+b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for random, you will see by default it produces a number between 0 and 1.

Basically this means that the expression you are looking for is:
ycord=-radius+random()*(radius*2);

This gives you a point on the y axis between -radius and radius (consider if the random() returns 0 you get -radius, it it returns 1 you get -radius+(2*radius())=radius.

You calculation for the x co-ordinate is correct but it gives you the x coordinate point on the circle (lets call it b). I suspect you want to use a new random to select an x co-ordinate between b and -b.