# Random dots inside a circle on a canvas

Tags: javascript, random, html5-canvas

I created a canvas and a circle on the canvas.

I'm trying to make random dots inside the circle by using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629872/canvas-for-drawing-is-a-circle-random-dots-within-canvas) but dots are being placed inside and outside the circle as well.

here's my code from the moment I create the circle:

```
 draw_circle(600, 600, 500);


            for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                 radius = 500;
                 y = 0;
                 x = 0;
                y = -radius + Math.random() * (radius + radius + 1);

                // x must respect x² + y² < r²
                xMax = Math.pow(Math.pow(radius, 2) - Math.pow(y, 2), 0.5);
                x = Math.random() * 2 * xMax - xMax;

            draw_circle(x, y, 3);
            }
```

and this is my draw_circle function:

```
 function draw_circle(x, y, r) {

         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
         ctx.stroke();
     }
```

Comment: Define "doesn't quite work".

Comment: dots are being placed mostly outside the circle and some inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are drawing your circle centred at `(600,600)`, but you are drawing your dots centred at `(0,0)`.

Try:

```
draw_circle(x+600, y+600, 3);
```